# How to open avi / wmv files in Quicktime (Windows)

Tags: windows, itunes, conversion, avi, quicktime

I want to add a couple of movies in wmv / avi format to my itunes library. I plan to use QuickTime to create a reference movie which can be read by itunes. But for that i need to be able to open these files in quicktime.

I had searched but i only find quicktime components/codecs for MAC. does anybody know any for windows?.

I could convert the files to mp4, for example but I want the same quality. I didn´t find the best tool/settings to do it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/downloads.php) is a great tool for video transcoding. It should be able to transcode your videos into a compatible format with the least quality degradation.

Comment: Handbrake it´s great but there is a little loss in color of my videos.